# getting the URL up to the port number

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets

I am currently doing services is java  that deploys to different machines, so what I need to to is to get the uri adddress up to the port number in the servlet who called it for example

http://localhost:8080/appname/appaddress

the only thing I need to get is the string from http to 8080 I can do this using javascript or java codes, thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**Location**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) object which has these following keys

`Location.origin` :origin of the specific location

`Location.port` :Gives port number

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript:

```
var baseUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;

if(window.location.port != "")
  baseUrl += ":" + window.location.port + "/";
```